# Searching the SVN repository

Tags: svn, search

I have gone through many links on this site and others but I could not find a helpful link helping me in indexing my SVN repository and then allowing me to search anything - comments, author, revision, file name, content of file etc.

I need a tool to search my complete repository. I tried SVN search its Indexer part was giving me an error "svn: Malformed network data".

One more thing I don't want any command line solution, I want a UI for this.

It will be helpful even if I get any indexer so that I can develop my own UI on the top of it.

PS - Researched about SVN query but not getting any resource for it. SupoSE looks like a closed project so I'm thinking of not using it.

Comment: You could use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)?

Comment: I have seen Trac also, but i am having one doubt is that project still supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> Researched about sVN query but not gettig any resource for it

site:
http://svnquery.tigris.org/

wiki:
http://svnquery.tigris.org/wiki/FrontPage

documentation:
http://svnquery.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=o0dpdE

demo:
http://svnquery.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=g8GcCC

In my experience SVNQuery is very popular, well-supported, and free.

Comment: By this i mean i am not getting the source code or executable for SVN query. I have seen all these links but they describe about it but they are of no help. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Hey i need to ask one more thing can we search the author, log message also using SVN query?

Comment: Yes, as the web site says, "Not only the content of a file is indexed, but also its complete metadata like path, author, comments and properties".

Answer (score 1):

Just idea:

- Clone SVN-repo to Mercurial (hg + hgsubversion)
- Use native hg-tools for search inside repo (grep, revsets /revset's keywords/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am looking something in C# or Java. SO that for future purpose i can extend it if i need to add some functionality

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for searching through subversion is SVNQUERY. This tool helps in Indexing and then searching. It provides the mechanism of Web Searching as well as  windows searching. Even it provides you with dll to use in ur own application. For more details about svn query visit http://svnquery.tigris.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely some valid suggestions above; don't want to detract from their relevance - but I found them all a bit over blown for what I wanted (just wanted to scan all our svn repos to look for Google Analytics UA codes so I know what projects to migrate to Firebase) so I wrote my own bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read line; do
svn checkout https://your-svn-server.com/$line
find $line/ -type f -exec grep -H 'text you want to search for' {} \; >> svn-log.txt
rm -rf $line
done < svn-list.txt
```

This checks out each repo one by one; scans them, then deletes the local copy of that repo & then checks out the next one.  svn-lines.txt is a list of all of your svn repo names.  The script assumes your your shell is already authorized to checkout all the repos in the list.  Instead of listing all of your repos in svn-list.txt you could incorporate the 'svn list' command into this script.  I didn't because our SVN server doesn't support that command at the top level.

Information regarding the files that are found to contain the search string is stored in svn-log.txt

Answer (score 0):

[VisualSVN Server 4.2](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/4.2/) supports searching by file or directory name. Try this feature on the [demo server](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/) and download VisualSVN Server from the [main download page](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/).

[image]

---

**Old answer**

Use the [`--search`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search) option with the [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command. Note that this command does not perform full-text search inside a repository, it considers the following data only:

- revision's author (`svn:author` unversioned property),
- date (`svn:date` unversioned property),
- log message text (`svn:log` unversioned property),
- list of changed paths (i.e. paths affected by the particular revision).